# How can I give check box in gridview a value that is not from the data source?

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net, checkbox, gridview

I have this gridview on an aspx page (Web form):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" showheader=false BorderStyle="None"CellPadding="4" GridLines="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" CssClass="wrapper5">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxFR" runat="server"/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="itemName" Text='<% # Eval("itemName") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="itemId" Text='<% #Eval("itemId") %>' runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

I have an array of itemIds that the user has. I want that the checkboxes in the same row as the itemIds will be checkd if the itemId is in the array.

This is what I tried in the code behind in c#:

```
public localhost.WebService1 w = new localhost.WebService1();
        public localhost.Item i = new localhost.Item();
        public localhost.MyUser u = new localhost.MyUser();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                int[] ei = w.SelectListOfUsersItemsIDS(1); //user number 1
                this.GridViewVG.DataSource = w.SelectListOfItems();
                this.GridViewVG.DataBind();
                for (int i = 0; i < ei.Length; i++)
                {
                    int item = ei[i];
                    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView.Rows)
                    {
                        Label l = (Label)row.FindControl("itemId");
                        if (l.Text != null)
                        {
                            int itemId = Convert.ToInt32(l.Text);
                            if (itemId == item)
                            {
                                CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBoxFR") as CheckBox;
                                checkbox.Checked = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I also tried using `private bool active;` and changing it to true when checking                        `if (itemId == item)` and it didn't work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The general answer here is to project the datasource to include this additional field before binding to the grid.

Specifically, we load data in these two lines:

```
int[] ei = w.SelectListOfUsersItemsIDS(1); //user number 1
this.GridViewVG.DataSource = w.SelectListOfItems();
```

You want to connect the `ei` data to the grid. We can do that *before* binding to the data source. In this code, I'm going to assume the object returned from `w.SelectListOfItems()` already has a field for `CheckBoxFR`, because it seems to already exist in the grid. If this is not the case, you'll to project into a new anonymous object, rather than simply setting the field in the `r` variable below, or alternatively edit the type definition used in `w.SelectListOfItems()` to include this field:

```
int[] ei = w.SelectListOfUsersItemsIDS(1); //user number 1
var data = w.SelectListOfItems();
var joined = data.Select(r => {
        r.CheckBoxFR = (int.TryParse(r.itemId, out int itemID) && ei.IndexOf(itemID)>=0);   
        return r;           
    });
this.GridViewVG.DataSource = joined;
```

Of, if `data` is populated based on a DataTable, DataReader, Dictionary, or similar, it might look like this:

```
int[] ei = w.SelectListOfUsersItemsIDS(1); //user number 1
var data = w.SelectListOfItems();
var joined = data.Select(r => {
        r["CheckBoxFR"] = (int.TryParse(r["itemId"], out int itemID) && ei.IndexOf(itemID)>=0);   
        return r;           
    });
this.GridViewVG.DataSource = joined;
```